# Como iniciar un proyecto JSP con una ruta en particular?

Tags: jsp, eclipse

Tengo un proyecto JSP antiguo para el cual uso eclipse como ide.

Una vez que todo esta configurado y pruebo que funciona, quiero que el mismo se inicie en otra ruta distinta a la ruta por defecto que lanza eclipse.

cuando lanzo el proyecto, el mismo se ejecuta en `http://localhost:8080/miapp/`. Pero yo quiero que al ejecutar, el mismo se ejecute en `http://localhost:8080/miapp/menu/mijsp.jsp`

Como bonus, quiero pasarle parametros para que quede de la forma: `http://localhost:8080/miapp/menu/mijsp.jsp?param1=aaa?param2=bbb`

Cuando lo ejecuto, y escribo la ruta a mano va a esa pagina, con lo cual el proyecto funciona.

La estructura de carpetas de mi proyecto es asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo supongo, que tengo que modificar algo en Deployment Descriptor, pero para variar no encuentro nada que me diga que modificar ni como...

Bonus extra: si alguien sabe como modificar la ruta para que donde dice miapp pueda cambiarlo, se lleva un cafe extra...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empiezo con el bonus extra:

Tomcat por defecto usa el nombre del fichero war como nombre de la aplicación. Al desplegar desde eclipse tienes que decirle al IDE que use otro nombre, lo que significa cambiar el "contexto" de `miapp` a algún otro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la otra pregunta:

¿Cómo usar `/menu` en lugar de `/`? Pues básicamente **redirigiendo**: mueve el fichero jsp que quieres cargar al directorio `/menu` y en raíz puedes poner un fichero index.jsp que reenvíe al navegador a donde quieres:

```
<c:redirect url="/menu/mijsp.jsp"/>
```

Una pega es que si quieres usar parámetros aquí, no se pasarán al destino.

Por tanto se podría hacer un `forward`, haciendo que ambas URLs sean equivalentes (en este caso no se envía al cliente a una nueva URL, sino que un JSP delega en otro:

```
<jsp:forward page="/menu/mijsp.jsp" />
```